# Android device is making always the same HTTP request or server giving always the same response? How is that possible?

Tags: php, android, json, httprequest

I am trying to make a POST HTTP request to a server but every time I get always the same json response, like the server responds always in the same way...
I have a GET which loads all municipalities data from a server, then another Activity which takes the municipality the user has been selected and should return a proper institutional info detail response. But what I get? I get the previous Json response of the previous HTTP get request in the previous activity.... How is that possible??? I even changed the URL and give it a fake name, but what I get is still the same GET response...

I do not know why android or my server behaves like this.

Here is the first activity:

```
public class IMieiDati extends ListActivity {

AutoCompleteTextView municipalityEditTxt;
EditText yearEditTxt;
EditText versed_moneyEditTxt;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
List<HashMap<String, String>> ListaComuni;
List<String> Anni;

private static final String URL_ANDROID_APP_LISTENER = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/android/AndroidAppListener.php";
// GET request infos
private static final String GET_QUERY_STRING[] = {"all_municipalities", "true"};
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_COMUNI = "municipalities";
private static final String TAG_ANNI = "years";
private static final String TAG_COMUNE_NOME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PROVINCIA_NOME = "provinceName";
private static final String TAG_SIGLA_PROVINCIA = "sign";
private static final String TAG_REGIONE_NOME = "regionName";

// POST request infos to pass to the HomeComune Activity with the putExtra() Intent method
private static final String TAG_COMUNE = "mun_name";
private static final String TAG_ANNO = "year";
private static final String TAG_VERSED_MONEY = "versed_money";

// municipalities JSON Array
JSONArray Comuni = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imiei_dati);

    // TxtViews
    municipalityEditTxt = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.municipality);
    yearEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year);
    versed_moneyEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.versed_money);

    // initializing empty collections
    ListaComuni = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Anni = new ArrayList<String>();

    // checking whether the network is not available
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Log.d("Message", "No network connection.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    new LoadAllMunicipalitiesThread().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.imiei_dati, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_forward:
                municipalityHome();
                return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
        default: 
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void municipalityHome() {
    // Recovering the values of the EditText items
    String municipalityName = municipalityEditTxt.getText().toString();
    String year = yearEditTxt.getText().toString();
    String versedMoney = versed_moneyEditTxt.getText().toString();

    // Checking whether the user has compiled all the fields
    // 1) Municipality. At least 2 chars, should be in the ListaComuni
    if (municipalityName.length()<2) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Inserisci un nome di comune valido.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    municipalityName = municipalityName.trim();
    boolean equals = false;
    for (HashMap<String, String> map : ListaComuni) {
        String pattern = map.get(TAG_COMUNE_NOME);
        if (pattern.equalsIgnoreCase(municipalityName)) {
            municipalityName = pattern;
            equals = true;
        }
    }
    if (!equals) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Inserisci un nome di comune valido.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }

    // 2) Year. Must be selected from the pop up. Must be in the range of the selectable years
    try {
        int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(year);
        int yearIntBottom = Integer.parseInt(Anni.get(0).toString());
        int yearIntTop = Integer.parseInt(Anni.get(Anni.size()-1).toString());

        if (yearInt < yearIntBottom || yearInt > yearIntTop) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Inserisci un anno valido.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            yearEditTxt.setText("");
            return;
        }
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Inserisci un anno valido.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        yearEditTxt.setText("");
        return;
    }

    // 3) Versed Money. Must be at least bigger than 1.
    try {
        float versedMoneyFloat = Float.parseFloat(versedMoney);
        if (versedMoneyFloat < 1) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Inserisci un importo valido." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Inserisci un importo valido.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    // defining the Intent  
    Intent open = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeComune.class);  
    // put extra data
    open.putExtra(TAG_COMUNE, municipalityName);
    open.putExtra(TAG_ANNO, year);
    open.putExtra(TAG_VERSED_MONEY, versedMoney);

    startActivity(open);  
}

private void openSettings() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Settings...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}


 // Background Async Task to Load all municipalities by making an HTTP GET Request
class LoadAllMunicipalitiesThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(IMieiDati.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... strings ){

        Log.d("ilMioComune", "Caricamento comuni");
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(GET_QUERY_STRING[0], GET_QUERY_STRING[1]));
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ANDROID_APP_LISTENER, "GET", params);

        Log.d("JSON GET comuni", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            // getting all municipalities
            if (success == 1) {
                JSONArray JSONmunicipalities = json.getJSONArray(TAG_COMUNI);

                // foreach Municipality JSONObject
                for (int i = 0; i < JSONmunicipalities.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject JSONmunicipality = JSONmunicipalities.getJSONObject(i);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // foreach Municipality's attributes
                    Iterator<?> MunicipalityKeys = JSONmunicipality.keys();
                    while (MunicipalityKeys.hasNext()) {
                        String MunicipalityKey = (String)MunicipalityKeys.next();
                        String MunicipalityValue = JSONmunicipality.getString(MunicipalityKey);
                        map.put(MunicipalityKey, MunicipalityValue);
                    }

                    // add Municipality HashMap to ListaComuni
                    ListaComuni.add(map);
                }

                // getting all years
                JSONArray JSONyears = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ANNI);

                // foreach Year JSONArray
                for (int i = 0; i < JSONyears.length(); i++) {
                    Anni.add(JSONyears.getString(i));
                }
            }
            else {
                // no municipalities or years were found
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        IMieiDati.this, ListaComuni,
                        R.layout.municipality_list_item, new String[] { 
                                TAG_COMUNE_NOME,
                                TAG_SIGLA_PROVINCIA,
                                TAG_PROVINCIA_NOME,
                                TAG_REGIONE_NOME
                                },
                        new int[] { R.id.name,
                                    R.id.sign,
                                    R.id.provinceName,
                                    R.id.regionName});

                // getting a years CharSequence array from Anni List.
                final CharSequence[] years = Anni.toArray(new CharSequence[Anni.size()]);
                // hide cursor in yearTxtView
                yearEditTxt.setCursorVisible(false);
                // yearTxtView onFocus Listener
                yearEditTxt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        yearEditTxt.requestFocus();
                        // Year pop up
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(IMieiDati.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Seleziona un anno");
                        builder.setItems(years, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // the user clicked on years[which]
                                yearEditTxt.setText(years[which]);
                                // if you want the cursor at the end of the string:
                                // yearTxtView.setSelection(yearTxtView.length());
                            }
                        });
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            // what to if user touches/taps on the EditText box
                            builder.show();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

}

The GET ?all_municipalities=true works as expected and I get the JSON:

```
JSON GET municipalities (2592): {"success":1,"years":["2013","2014"],"municipalities":[{"regionName":"Emilia-Romagna","sign":"(FC)","provinceName":"Forlì-Cesena","name":"Cesena"},{"regionName":"Emilia-Romagna","sign":"(FC)","provinceName":"Forlì-Cesena","name":"Forlì"},{"regionName":"Emilia-Romagna","sign":"(PR)","provinceName":"Parma","name":"Parma"},{"regionName":"Emilia-Romagna","sign":"(RA)","provinceName":"Ravenna","name":"Ravenna"},{"regionName":"Emilia-Romagna","sign":"(RN)","provinceName":"Rimini","name":"Riccione"},{"regionName":"Emilia-Romagna","sign":"(RN)","provinceName":"Rimini","name":"Rimini"},{"regionName":"Emilia-Romagna","sign":"(RA)","provinceName":"Ravenna","name":"Russi"}]}
```

Now the second activity, when the user sends POST data to the server:

```
public class HomeComune extends Activity {

// widgets 
Button infoListButton;

/////////////////////////////////////////////
List<String> masterList;
Map<String, List<String>> detailMap; 
ExpandableListView expListView;

String municipalityName;
String year;
String versedMoney;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// the context of this activity. Will be used when creating the institutional info dialog
private Context thisContext = this; 

// POST request information
private static String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/android/AndroidListener2.php";
private static final String TAG_COMUNE = "mun_name";
private static final String TAG_ANNO = "year";
private static final String TAG_VERSED_MONEY = "versed_money";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
// JSON data retrieving information
private static final String JSON_INSTITUTIONAL_INFOS_LABEL = "institutional_infos"; 
private static final String JSON_MASTER_LABEL = "master";
private static final String JSON_DETAIL_LABEL = "detail";
private static final String JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_NAME_LABEL = "name";
```

//  private static final String JSON_DETAIL_NUMBER_LABEL = "number";

```
// institutional info JSON Array which will contain the Master and Detail data that will come from the POST request
JSONArray institutionalInfo = null;

// institutional info Hash Map for the Master and Detail Hash Map
HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> institutionalInfoCollection;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_comune);

    createGroupList();

    createCollection();


    Intent myDataIntent = this.getIntent();
    // getting the municipality name, the year and the versed money from the prev. intent
    this.municipalityName = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_COMUNE);
    this.year = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_ANNO);
    this.versedMoney = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_VERSED_MONEY);

    // POST request Async Task
    new LoadAllMunicipalityInfoThread().execute();

    infoListButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
}

class LoadAllMunicipalityInfoThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeComune.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        Log.d("ilMioComune", "Caricamento Info Istituzionali");
        // building the HTTP POST request
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_COMUNE, municipalityName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ANNO, year));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_VERSED_MONEY, versedMoney));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

        Log.d("JSON POST info istituzionali", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            // getting all institutional infos of a municipality
            if (success == 1) {
                institutionalInfo = json.getJSONArray(JSON_INSTITUTIONAL_INFOS_LABEL);

                // foreach institutional info JSONObject
                for (int i = 0; i<institutionalInfo.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject JSONinstitutionalInfo = institutionalInfo.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject JSONmasterEntry = JSONinstitutionalInfo.getJSONObject(JSON_MASTER_LABEL);

                    String masterEntryName = JSONmasterEntry.getString(JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_NAME_LABEL);
                    masterList.add(masterEntryName);

                    JSONArray JSONdetails = JSONmasterEntry.getJSONArray(JSON_DETAIL_LABEL);

                    List<String> detailNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                    // foreach detail in JSONdetails
                    for (int j = 0; j<JSONdetails.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject JSONdetailEntry = JSONdetails.getJSONObject(j);

                        String detailEntryName = JSONdetailEntry.getString(JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_NAME_LABEL);
                    //  String detailEntryNumber = JSONdetailEntry.getString(JSON_DETAIL_NUMBER_LABEL);

                        detailNames.add(detailEntryName);
                    }
                    detailMap.put(masterEntryName, detailNames);
                }
            }
            else {
                // no institutional infos associated to the municipality in the selected year were found
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                infoListButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                     @Override
                      public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        // custom dialog
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(thisContext);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.institutional_info_custom_list);
                        dialog.setTitle("Info");
                        // getting the window manager and changing the dialog position
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
                        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                        params.y = 80;
                        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
                        // dialog width and height.
                        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   

                        // inflating the custom institutional expandable list layout
                        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) thisContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.institutional_info_custom_list, null, false);
                        dialog.setContentView(v);

                        expListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                        final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(HomeComune.this, masterList, detailMap);
                        expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

                        dialog.show();
                      }
                });
            }
        });         
    }
}




 }
```

And instead of getting the proper JSON Post response, I get the previous GET.... Even if I have changed the name of the .php script where the listener is waiting for a POST request....

How is that possible??? I can't believe my self... Maybe I am wrong somewhere... But in the .php AndroidListener2.php I check those variables:

```
if (isset($_POST['mun_name']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['versed_money']))
{
        // recover the proper data and send the JSON response ...
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

First of all add the following flag to your intent "open"

```
open.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Then in your other Activity put this part of your code

```
createGroupList();

createCollection();


Intent myDataIntent = this.getIntent();
// getting the municipality name, the year and the versed money from the prev. intent
this.municipalityName = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_COMUNE);
this.year = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_ANNO);
this.versedMoney = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_VERSED_MONEY);

// POST request Async Task
new LoadAllMunicipalityInfoThread().execute();

infoListButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
```

inside a new method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

}
```

The issue is, when you use `this.getIntent();` it retrieves the first `Intent` used to start the `Activity` and not the new one. This causes it to always retrieve the data from the first `Intent` used so the Extras are always the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I found the problem, it was a server side mistake in my php code. By the way I still can't explain why the server response was the previous GET request, cause when the app makes the second POST request the GET variables are not set... mystery of nature.

Comment: Mysteries of web development...and It in general. Sometimes you can't understand a thing

Answer (score 1):

You have to erase or clear all the data from Json and all ArrayLists you are using before adding new data.

You can do that in the method:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       json.clear();
       ListaComuni.clear();
       detailMap.clear();
     // and all the HashMap or ArrayLists you declared and want to put in them new data
    }
```